# Testing - Test for Specific Paths?

Tags: programming-practices, unit-testing, testing

When (unit) testing, is is bad to expect the code to use certain paths.

For example, should I be testing for specifically `"/build/static/public/css/"`, or just that `server.cssPath` has been set to a string and is a valid path?

I'm testing a web server.

Comment: what kind of application are you testing?

Comment: @gnat, I updated the question.

Comment: There is a distinction between "white-box" testing that knows about implementation details, and "black-box" testing that only worries about the functionality you're trying to implement. If that's what you're thinking of, both are considered valid as far as I know.

Comment: @Ixrec, Thanks! Is one considered "better"?

Comment: Black-box is better for unit testing, when you want to ensure your functionality/API remains stable. White-box is better for regression testing, when you want to ensure specific bugs or other issues you've seen in the past don't come back. If I had to pick only one, it'd probably be black-box, but again it depends on your goals and what difficulties you expect to have.

Comment: @Ixrec the way I understand white-box testing, it is more useful for unit testing because the structure of the component under test has to be known. Black-box testing are usually generated based on the specifications and could be more relevant for acceptance testing since the structure of the system under test must not be known.

Comment: To me it's still black-box as long as you're only testing the public API of a class, even if that class is a tiny piece of the whole product and has no direct relation to anything in the spec. Either way, the question is definitely too vague or broad; any answers posted now would be just as subjective as these comments we're making.

Comment: Is the path statically or dynamically generated? If it is dynamic, then you can maybe test for a specific one. I like to reference the same string constants the app uses when possible - that's one way to help. But if it's static, well - what are you really getting by testing? I think then you care more about the "qualities" of the path, not the value - is it assigned, does the path exist, etc. About the only exception I've seen to this is if a path is really, really important and that changing it in one place will unexpectedly break something else (bad!) - then it's a warning to others.

Comment: @JTrana that's actually a great way to put it, could you put in in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the path statically or dynamically generated?

If it is dynamic, then you can maybe test for a specific path because there is importance in testing the calculation of the path. I like to reference the same string constants the app uses when possible - that's one way to help.

But if it's static, well - what are you really getting by testing? I think then you care more about the "qualities" of the path, not the value - is it assigned, does the path exist, etc.

About the only exception I've seen to this is if a path is really, really important and that changing it in one place will unexpectedly break something else (bad!) - then it's a warning to others.